# How to convert nested sql query to zend 1.12 format

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

**My Query:**

```
select distinct ml.send_to from message_log as ml where NOT exists
(select mobile_no from user_details WHERE user_details.mobile_no = ml.send_to);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$select1 = $db->select()->from('user_details',array('mobile_no'))
                  ->where('user_details.mobile_no = ml.send_to');

$select2 = $db->select()->distinct()
               ->from(array('ml'=>'message_log'), array('ml.send_to')))
               ->where('NOT EXISTS ?', $select1);
```

This will do the trick in the easiest way.

Comment: Glad to hear that :). Could you mark the answer as correct, please?

Answer (score 0):

you can use customer query in zend as

```
$sql = 'select distinct ml.send_to from message_log as ml where NOT exists
(select mobile_no from user_details WHERE user_details.mobile_no = ml.send_to);';

 $stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli($db, $sql);
 $stmt->execute();
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   echo $row['send_to'];
 }
```

this will really help you

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.statement.html